# Variables in batch job

Tags: batch-file

I´ve a small issue with using variables in a batch job - maybe someone can help me.
That´s the call:

```
BCompare.exe @"versioncompare-script.txt" "..\1.0.0\source" "build\template" "doc/version-compare/version-compare-templates.html"
```

Now I´m replacing version numbers in the batch job with variables which leads to the following call:

```
set previousversion=1.0.0 
BCompare.exe @"versioncompare-script.txt" "..\%previousversion%\source" "build\template" "doc/version-compare/version-compare-templates.html"
```

For any reason this leads to an exception in Beyond compare caused by to many arguments passed.

Has anybody an idea, what the issue could be?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an aditional space at the end of the assignment.

```
set previousversion=1.0.0 
                         ^ Here a space is added to variable value
```

Change to

```
set "previousversion=1.0.0"
```

Quotes are used to delimit the assignment but are not included in the value

Comment: @Michael: You could also simply delete the space but it is a good idea to enclose assignments in quotes like this because this way it is more obvious there are no trailing spaces.